# Set alpha according to gradient with imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

Is it possible to set the alpha channel of an image according to a gradient with ImageMagick?

I'd like the pixels on the left border of an image to be 100% transparent, and the ones on the right border to be 100% opaque, and with the ones in the middle having progressively lower transparency values.

Or in a more general case - given a grayscale image, set the alpha channel of another image as a function of the B&W values (`black = 100% alpha, white 0% alpha`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ImageMagick you can use `-sparse-color` to apply a gradient only to the alpha channel to get the result you describe.

```
convert in.png -alpha set -background none -channel A \
    -sparse-color barycentric "0,0 none %[w],0 white" +channel out.png
```

That command starts by activating the alpha channel and setting the background color to transparent. Then it uses `-channel A` to apply the following operation only to the alpha channel. The `-sparse-color` operation tells it to start with transparent at the far left edge, pixel `0,0` and graduate to opaque at pixel `%[w],0`. The `%[w]` means the width or far right edge.

Although there are many ways to accomplish the effect you've described, by using `-sparse-color` you can easily make the gradient start and end at any positions on the image without having to create any intermediate masking images.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. You would use `-composite CopyOpacity` to set the alpha channel from a gradient mask.

Given I  have the following images. `image.png` & `transparent_mask.png`

[image] [image: transparent_mask]

We can set the image transparency (where black is alpha, and white is opaque) by copying values from the mask image to the input image alpha channel.

```
convert image.png transparent_mask.png -compose CopyOpacity -composite output.png
```

[image: output]

Comment: When I tried this the output image had a white background with no transparency.